# How to list Github repositories with Hybridauth?

Tags: php, list, github, repository, hybridauth

I try to mix Github Documentation : https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories

and Hybridauth functions to get the list of repositories of the user who is logged by hybridauth.

I have something like that which returns nothing for the moment.

```
/**
* load the user's repositories
*/
function getUserRepos()
   {
      $data = $this->api->api( "user/repos" );

      $this->user->repos->full_name  = @ $data->name;

      return $this->user->repos;
   }
```

EDIT : This is the good way to do it :

```
/**
* load the user's repositories
*/

function getUserRepos()
{
    $data = $this->api->api( "user/repos" );
    foreach($this->api->get("user/repos") as $repos){
        return $repos;
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't giving us enough information. What is `$this->api->api()`? What does `$data` contain after that call (e.g. if you `var_dump()` or `print_r()` it)? It is very likely that your use of [`@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) is stomping on the error message that would help troubleshoot this.

Comment: This is exactly the coding structure of hybridauth that's why I didn't explain more. I just copy the actions from here : https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/master/additional-providers/hybridauth-github/Providers/GitHub.php

Comment: And what about my other questions? Did you inspect `$data` and see what it contains?

Comment: $data is getting the data about the repos. This is the return which doesn't work.